# save applet from website

Tags: applet, save

how can I save a java applet from a website so I can run it offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the url of the classes by looking at the applet tag and download them.  You can use FIrebug in Firefox or Fiddler to see the URL's being requested as the page loads if you can't figure it out from the applet tag.